# Dotnet 6 Factory Class with Dependency injection and arguments passed in factory

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I tried to make this work with arguments which i pass in factory, but i could not force it to work. It works when Factory class handles Class Service which does not have any other things that these handled by Dependency Injection. But let the code speak for itself.

Interface

```cs
public interface IBook
{
    string ReadableType { get; set; }
    string ReturnPage(int pageNumber);
}
```

Base Class

```cs
public abstract class BaseBook
{
    protected readonly IFileSystem _fileSystem;
    protected readonly IShelf _shelf;
    protected string _title;
    protected string _author;

    protected BaseBook(IFileSystem fileSystem, IShelf shelf, string title, string author)
    {
        _fileSystem = fileSystem;
        _shelf = shelf;
        _title = title;
        _author = author;
    }
}
```

Class 1

```cs
public class Novel : BaseBook, IBook
{
    public string ReadableType { get; set ;} = "Novel";
    protected readonly ILogger<Novel> _logger;
    
    public Novel(ILogger<Novel> logger, IFileSystem fileSystem, IShelf shelf, string title, string author)
        : base(fileSystem, shelf, title, author)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        
    }

    public string ReturnPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        // my implementation of Method...
    }
}
```

Class 2

```cs
public class ShortNovel : BaseBook, IBook
{
    public string ReadableType { get; set ;} = "ShortNovel";
    protected readonly ILogger<ShortNovel> _logger;
    
    public ShortNovel(ILogger<ShortNovel> logger, IFileSystem fileSystem, IShelf shelf, string title, string author)
        : base(fileSystem, shelf, title, author)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        
    }

    public string ReturnPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        // my implementation of Method...
    }
}
```

Factory class and interface.

```cs
public interface IBookFactory
{
    IBook Create(string readableType, string title, string author);
}

public class BookFactory : IBookFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public BookFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IBook Create(string readableType, string title, string author)
    {
        if (readableType == "Novel")
        {
            return  ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Novel>(_serviceProvider, title, author);
        }
        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ShortNovel>(_serviceProvider, title, author);
    }
}
```

Finally i bind it to `IServiceCollection` services.

```cs
services.AddTransient<IBook, Novel>();
services.AddTransient<IBook, ShortNovel>();
services.AddTransient<Func<IBook>>(x => () => x.GetService<Novel>()!);
services.AddTransient<Func<IBook>>(x => () => x.GetService<ShortNovel>()!);
```

When I try to run it i get error:

```
Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: 
...MYNAMESPACE...Interfaces.IBook 
Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: ...MYNAMESPACE...Novel': 
Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate '...MYNAMESPACE....Novel'.
```

So far i tried a lot of things, but this is as far as i could go. It looks like i create instance in factory in incorrect way or i had made mistake in my service bindings.

Comment: What do your service registrations have to do with your factory? The last two sections of your question seem to deal with registering `Novel`, for which constructor parameters are unavailable/unknown, and then creating a `Func<IBook>` from that, but it still has the problem that the parameters are unknown. That doesn't seem to have any relationship to the rest of the code you've shown. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're asking though.

Comment: I tried to add `title` and `author` to the IBook Interface, but i still have the same error.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Are you trying to remove `BookFactory` and refactor its functions to pure ASP.NET Core DI?

Comment: So i could use the BookFactory and return given instance of Novel or ShortNovel when needed `IBook book = _bookFactory.Create(bookType, title, author)`.

Comment: It seems that your `BookFactory` already does that without the registration in the penultimate code block of your question.

Comment: It would work without the `title` and `author` these arguments which i try to pass are causing problems.

Comment: It [works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2VmhwU). Can you provide a better reproduction case, please?

Comment: The most surprising thing is that it works for me to. This is unfortunate not a production code, i had to make example, because i could not post here production code. So it seems that in production i had an error, but in example i did not make an error. Is this a reversed Murphy Law?!

Comment: It's sometimes the way it is, unfortunately. That being said, it usually points to a difference between your actual code and the sample, so at least you can start to play "spot the difference" now. :D

Answer (score 0):

Answer if someone will have similar problem. The bind to `IServiceCollection` was  an issue here:

Incorrect

```cs
services.AddTransient<IBook, Novel>();
services.AddTransient<IBook, ShortNovel>();
services.AddTransient<Func<IBook>>(x => () => x.GetService<Novel>()!);
services.AddTransient<Func<IBook>>(x => () => x.GetService<ShortNovel>()!);
```

Correct

```cs
services.AddTransient<IBookFactory, BookFactory>();
```